# My window doesnt remain active after i click on "async" method button

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

i have the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int res = WaitFiveSecMethod();
        this.text2.Text = res.ToString();
    }

    private int WaitFiveSecMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return 5;
    }

    private async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var res = await WaitFiveSecMethodAsync();
        this.text1.Text = res;

    }

    private async Task<string> WaitFiveSecMethodAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return "5";
    }

}
```

I want to show the difference between clicking the "sync" button (button 2) and clicking the "async" button (button 3). clicking both buttons should do the same time-consuming calculations (in my case represented with "Thread.Sleep(5000)").
Currently using async and wait make my client stuck i thought these keywords shouldn't block my client thread.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code below works synchronously and block UI, not async:

```
private async Task<string> WaitFiveSecMethodAsync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return "5";
}
```

Remember async has just responsibility to enable `await` keyword, if you don't have `await`, `async` is meaningless and turn to synchronous. So, async method must have at least one `await` keyword inside.

The better way is, you should *delay* by *awaiting* `Task.Delay` which does not block your UI thread:

```
private async Task<string> WaitFiveSecMethodAsync() 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(5000); 
    return "5"; 
}
```

Comment: but i want to demonstrate a long calculation that wont stuck the client..if i am using task.delay i am already starting a new thread.. so whats the use of async ans await?

Comment: but i want to  show the difference between async and sync method that do the same operations. if i'll use the Task.Delay it will NOT stuck the client in sync method because i am staring a new thread with it... so what will be the use of await and async?

Comment: don't understand you much, what is the point with your question? you state *I can't make it asynchronous, when i click "button 3" the client is stuck*

Comment: So and the end of every async flow i need to have some system method that support async? i thought i could make async method by myself... lets say: replacing the Task.Delay with a time-consuming calculation on the same tread...

Comment: @OriPrice: You can use `Task.Run` to easily put time-consuming calculations on a thread pool thread.